# bind combobox column in datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have a combobox which contain 4 elements "REF" "DF" "OVEN" "Chest cooler", this combobox is bind with sql.

Now I want when I select "REF" the all modal of Ref show in grid combo column when I select DF the all modal of DF show in grid combo column "Modal". For this purpose I will make the tables in sql.

Please tell who to get the grid combo box and who to bind.

```
if (combocate.Text.ToString() == "REFRIGATOR")
{
    string query = "select ID,Modal from modal where categoryID= 1";
}
```